# Converting Strings to booleans when converting XML to JSON

Tags: java, xml, json

This block of code essentially takes a JAXB Object and turns it into a JSONObject

```
  StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
  marshaller.marshal(jaxbObj, stringWriter);
  try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(stringWriter.toString());
    resp.getOutputStream().write(jsonObject.toString(2).getBytes());

  } catch (JSONException e) {
    throw new ServletException("Could not parse JSON",e);
  }
```

Unfortunately, this transformation doesn't turn, say, a String like "true" into a boolean, leaving the poor front end guy to do it.

I would think that I want to somehow map over the values in the JSONObject, calling [stringToValue](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#stringToValue(java.lang.String)) on each. I have a feeling there is a better way. Any ideas?

Comment: A decent JSON implementation will turn Strings into Strings and not try to do any telepathic data type guessing. But by the same token, it should turn valid booleans into valid booleans... care to show us some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, JAXB itself won't even produce JSON to begin with, so you are using something else in addition (maybe use it via Jersey). So maybe package in question has something.

But why try to do this with org.json objects? Just use regular Java bean with expected type, create that from whatever input bean you have. No need for magic, just explicit code.

Comment: Since the JSON was fairly simple, I did end up using explicit code for the project in question. Thanks for your feedback.